# Postfix outgoing SMTP: "connection timed out"

Tags: server, email, postfix

I have a little problem with my postfix. The thing is that I can receive emails but when I send an email I get a Connection timed out error.

```
connect to outlook-com.olc.protection.outlook.com[104.47.5.33]:25: Connection timed out
```

This is happening with all the emails I send and not just with outlook. I already searched for solutions for this problem but couldn't find anything useful.

This is my main.cf:

```
# This file was automatically installed on 2019-06-27T15:11:55.824661
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
myhostname = webmail.apt-one.com
myorigin = $myhostname
mydestination = $myhostname
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
biff = no
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 550

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 11534336
recipient_delimiter = +

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

## Proxy maps
proxy_read_maps =
        proxy:unix:passwd.byname
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domains.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domain- aliases.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-aliases.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relaydomains.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-maintain.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relay-recipient-verification.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-sender-login-map.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-spliteddomains-transport.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-transport.cf
## TLS settings
#
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = 
${config_directory}/dh2048.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = 
btree:$data_directory/smtpd_tls_session_cache
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes

# Disallow SSLv2 and SSLv3, only accept secure ciphers
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2, !TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high

smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, RSA, eNULL, aNULL
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, RSA, eNULL, aNULL
smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, RSA, eNULL, aNULL
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, RSA,  eNULL, aNULL
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes

# Enable elliptic curve cryptography
smtpd_tls_eecdh_grade = ultra

# Use TLS if this is supported by the remote SMTP server, otherwise use plaintext.
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1

smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scach
smtp_tls_key_file = /etc/nginx/privkey.pem
smtp_tls_cert_file = /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem

## Virtual transport settings#
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domains.cf
virtual_alias_domains = proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-domain-aliases.cf
virtual_alias_maps =
    proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-aliases.cf

## Relay domains#
relay_domains =
    proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql- 
relaydomains.cf
transport_maps =
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-transport.cf
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-spliteddomains-transport.cf

## SASL authentication through Dovecot#
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

## SMTP session policies#

# We require HELO to check it later
smtpd_helo_required = yes

# We do not let others find out which 
recipients are valid
disable_vrfy_command = yes

# MTA to MTA communication on Port 25. We expect (!) the other party to
# specify messages as required by RFC 821.
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes

# Verify cache setup
address_verify_map = 
proxy:btree:$data_directory/verify_cache

proxy_write_maps =
    $smtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
    $lmtp_sasl_auth_cache_name
    $address_verify_map

# OpenDKIM setup
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12345
non_smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:12345
milter_default_action = accept
milter_content_timeout = 30s

# List of authorized senders
smtpd_sender_login_maps =
        proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-sender-login-map.cf

# Recipient restriction rules
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
      permit_mynetworks
      permit_sasl_authenticated
      check_recipient_access
          proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-maintain.cf
          proxy:pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql-relay-recipient-verification.cf
      reject_unverified_recipient
      reject_unauth_destination
      reject_non_fqdn_sender
      reject_non_fqdn_recipient
      reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname

## Postcreen settings#
postscreen_access_list =
   permit_mynetworks
   cidr:/etc/postfix/postscreen_spf_whitelist.cidr
postscreen_blacklist_action = enforce

# Use some DNSBL
postscreen_dnsbl_sites =
        zen.spamhaus.org*3
        bl.spameatingmonkey.net*2
        dnsbl.habl.org
        bl.spamcop.net
        dnsbl.sorbs.net
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 3
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce

postscreen_greet_banner = Welcome, please wait...
postscreen_greet_action = enforce

postscreen_pipelining_enable = yes
postscreen_pipelining_action = enforce

postscreen_non_smtp_command_enable = yes
postscreen_non_smtp_command_action = enforce

postscreen_bare_newline_enable = yes
postscreen_bare_newline_action = enforce
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: did you try to manually connect to that `[104.47.5.33]:25` host:port with -for example- a simple `telnet 104.47.5.33 25` and with dns name too

Comment: Yes, I did. I get connection timed out.

Comment: In that case you know that there is a network (routing, filtering,...) issue and probably not related to postfix.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of ISPs block outbound connections on port 25.  ATT consumer/residential plans, as of the time of writing, all seem to block it.  You may be able to change this in your ISP-provided router's configuration, or ask your ISP to allow it for your client at the gateway...